# Exclude all images from 301 redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have successfully done a 301 redirect from **blog.domain.com** to **newdomain.com** using the below code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But now i want to exclude all images from redirecting. How can i stop redirecting the urls which end with .jpg or .png,
To be more clear i dont want to redirect the below urls

http://blog.domain.com/image.jpg

http://blog.domain.com/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude images from you redirect rule, put the following condition above your rule:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(jpe?g|png|gif)$ [NC]
```

This will exclude all those requests that end with **jpeg** , **jpg** , **png** and **gif** .

Comment: Thanks man, its worked.
Early i was used this code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.jpg|/.png|/.gif)$ [NC] 
but it didn't work. Now i know what was the mistake